# How to manipulate an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array like:

```
A=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,],[2,5,7,5,3,6,89,2],[22,44,55,77,88,34,44,66]]
```

I need them like:

```
C=[1,2,22] d=[2,5,44] e=[3,7,55]........ j=[8,2,66]
```

how to do it in python kindly help.

Comment: `[list(x) for x in zip(*A)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip without the need for writing the craziness you are talking about.

```
[list(i) for i in zip(*A)]
```

Likewise

```
name='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
for n,i in enumerate(zip(*Arr)):
    globals() [ str(name[n]) ]=i
```

Output

```
print(A) #[1,2,22]

print(B)  #[2,5,44]
...
```

Comment: Hi @Shadowcodder- I tried using this code , it shows just "[ ]". There is no data in it.

Comment: `Arr` is the array. And `print(A),print(B),... `To get the desired output.

Comment: Yeah that helped , thanks a lot @ Shadowcodder

Comment: @Got Craziness If the answer help, then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with zip:

```
[[a,b,c] for a,b,c in zip(*A)]
```

Comment: hi @Christian Sloper. The data I showed up is just a sample. There are 10,000 values stored in similar way [ [ * ],[ * ],[ * ],[ * ] ]

Comment: in that case, look at Shadowcodders solution.